# SOAP using Spring MVC, JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, soap, web

I'm learning how to use SOAP, what I want to do basically consists of making a web page using SOAP with Spring MVC to retrieve data from a database. I've been studying how to use Spring MVC but I don't understand how I can make it SOAP. Basically, how to structure it? What to use? Should I use Spring-WS alongside Spring MVC? I must say I'm pretty new in Spring MVC and SOAP.

I really appreciate any given help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps you need to take

1. Need to add below dependencies

   spring-ws-core wsdl4j
2. create an xsd which stands for XML Schema Definition.
   Your domain  will be in  schema file (XSD) that Spring-WS will export automatically as a WSDL.
3. Generate domain classes based on an XML schema. It can be done using maven plugin
4. Create some kind of db repository which would serve the data to the web service
5. Create a service endpoint to use the repo. It is done so that we don't expose the logic to the user we just give the service name that should be called. service handles everything for us. Kind of abstraction
6. Configure web service beans. Below is the link to a detailed tutorial to make a spring based soap web service

http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-soap-web-service-producer-consumer-example-with-tomcat

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question. If I have the MVC structure, what else do I have to add to make it SOAP? Spring WS, or what?  And is that example using spring MVC? 
Thanks again

Comment: The tutorial is spring based but not spring mvc kind of . You can eventually convert it to spring mvc. The tutorial explains everything that needs to be added to your project

Comment: Thanks a lot kind stranger!

Comment: Can you please up vote the answer and accept  if it helped you